# Moving PyCharm .idea directory

Tags: django, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to move the PyCharm `.idea` directory out of the project folder (a django project in this case).

I followed the instructions from JetBrains to move the `.idea.properties` file, which involves creating a custom `.idea.properties` file. I figured this might also provide a means to move the `.idea` folder, but having done this, it does not appear to have addressed the issue and if I create a new Django project the .idea directory is still in the Django project folder.  I have looked at the contents of the custom `.idea.properties` file and although there is an entry relating to where it looks for `.idea` files to flag them as such, it doesn't appear to actually have a specific setting for the location of the `.idea` directory it creates for new projects.

As is often the case with JetBrains, I feel like I am missing the point somewhere and in this case searching on StackExchange or more general googling has not shed any light on the problem.

There is a workaround that I found that is in a nine-year old thread on the JetBrains 'YouTrack' bug tracking system (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102?p=WI-343) but it refers to changing the Settings|Directories option in PyCharm, which I cannot locate although there are many items in the settings that refer to different directories.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aside the fact that it's not so easy to do. What's the underlying reason you want to move it outside of the project? Maybe there's another way to cope with your issue.

Comment: Not a PyCharm user. Where in that IDE you specify content roots? The idea is the same: 1) create project elsewhere (where you want to keep your `.idea`) 2) Go to that settings page (Additional Content Roots) and add actual content root instead of current empty one. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-content-roots.html

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm syncing projects via OneDrive and there is NO way on this thing to pattern match exclusions, so I would like to store .idea folder outside of Onedrive folder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving `.idea` directory, you can create new PyCharm project than add Content Root as original project folder.

This way you can work on the same code in different PyCharm instances

- in PyCharm to change project's [Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html) go to File | Settings | Project:  | Project Structure.

See [work in IDEA and PyCharm for the same project at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68829992/work-in-idea-and-pycharm-for-the-same-project-at-the-same-time)