# work in IDEA and PyCharm for the same project at the same time

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, pycharm

There is a project like https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code that has java and python code mixed.

The problem is open IDEA for java code, and then open PyCharm to work with Python,
after a while when I return to IDEA I get error like

> java: Cannot find JDK 'Python 3.9' for module 'Recent-Tweet-Counts'

I checked throu `.iml` and other files under `./idea` but could not find if I could play with that configuration manually.

So the question is how to work in IDEA and PyCharm for the same project at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm share same [project configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#project-formats) files but use different formats.

So if you want to work on the same project at the same time in two IDEs, as a workaround you should save project configuration files (the `.idea` directory) in different locations for PyCharm and IDEA. You can do so by first creating a new project in a directory where you want to keep `.idea` project configuration files and then change the content root for the created module in project structure settings:

- in IDEA to change the module's [Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html) go to File | Project Structure | Modules | `<module name>` | Sources tab
- in PyCharm to change project's [Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html) go to File | Settings | Project:  | Project Structure.

Related usability requests are:

- [IDEA-140707](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140707) CLion interferes with PyCharm and vice-versa
- [IDEA-170102](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102) Add ability to save project info (.idea) outside of project folder

---

In short: work in IDEA as usual, and for PyCharm create new project in other folder and add Content Root as original project folder.

Comment: Worked great. I created new PyCahrm project, and PyCharm created new venv as well. Then in built-in terminal `pip install requests` (or whatever dependency you need) and .py code is runnable now

Comment: I have the same problem but with Clion and Pycharm.

Comment: I had the opposite problem: working mainly with Python PyCharm, but wanted to use Idea to edit some Groovy files on the same project and was then having conflicts with the Groovy library. Following @Andrey's advice the way around worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IDEA Ultimate can work on Python, PHP, Ruby, and JS projects etc, just install the the corresponding language plugin.

IDEA behaves *slightly* different than the language specific IDES though, mostly with regard to Modules and Projects. The other IDEs don't expose the Module abstraction unless you try to open another project then click the add button; in IDEA, Modules are exposed all the time.